# Series solution to differential equations with equal indicial roots

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to understand solved example 10 in attached photo. I am able to understand the steps except the last step (equation 97). I could not follow how substituting 95 in 88 gives the last step ( equation 97)[image]

Comment: Could you show us your working? The requirement upon resolving $(97)$ seems simple enough. Once we see your attempted solution, it may be easier for us to help you.

Comment: This is how I attempted to obtain equation 97. However after the last step mentioned by me below .... I felt I was grossly going wrong somewhere as even combining like terms for powers of x was not getting me anywhere near the solution

Comment: I am unable to attach the photo of how I attempted to get step 97 and the equations. But I calculated y' (2 terms) and y''(4 terms). Then I substituted values of y, y' and y'' in equation 88 and tried to collect coefficients of x^{k}, x^{(k-1)} and x^{(k-2)} together...but the resulting expression was too complicated and nowhere close to 97... I am grossly going wrong somewhere .... If I can be helped to indicate as to how to attach a photo of my solution in this box, I will do so.  I have understood the steps after  97 (not attached in above photo).I req help for getting 97 from 95 and 88